# Create a new dictionary using an existing one and list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, dictionary

If I had:

```
adict = {'a':3, 'b':6, 'c':9, 'd':12}
alist = ['a', 'z', 't', 's']
```

How would I create a new dict with the keys of the first dict and the items of the list, resulting in this?

```
bdict = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'z', 'c': 't', 'd': 's'}
```

Comment: You can't do this, dictionaries are not ordered, unlike lists

Comment: Unless you don't care about order

Comment: Are a-d, z, t, s variables? Or strings?

Comment: Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) maybe

Answer (score 3):

To bring the keys of *adict* together the values from *alist* use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> adict = OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 6), ('c', 9), ('d', 12)])
>>> alist = ['a', 'z', 't', 's']
>>> bdict = OrderedDict(zip(adict, alist))
>>> bdict
OrderedDict([('a', 'a'), ('b', 'z'), ('c', 't'), ('d', 's')])
```

I've used ordered dictionaries here because the question only makes sense if the dictionaries are [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)s; otherwise, you can't guarantee the pairwise one-to-one correspondence between *adict* and *alist*.